# Is this DB2 cursor a loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, db2, cursor

<strike>Through fate or luck,</strike> I am working on converting DB2 stored procedures to SQL Server stored procedures.

One thing I could not completely understand in DB2 is cursors<sup>1</sup>. By looking at it and reading some documentation, it appears that it is only a select statement.

```
-- DB2 stored procedure code
declare entity_cursor cursor with return for
select *
from TableName;

...
--a lot more cursors like above, and some other code
...

open entity_cursor;
```

**Questions**

1. Am I correct in my assumption<sup>2</sup> that this is only a `select` statement *actually* returning a result set when the cursor is opened?
2. If an error has occurred *before* the cursor is opened<sup>3</sup>, will the SP return a blank result set for `entity_cursor`?

---

<sup>1</sup>: I know that SQL Server they are commonly used for performing operations on row-by-row.
<sup>2</sup>: Based on reading DB2 documentation and a little on my knowledge and intellect.
<sup>3</sup>: Unfortunately I cannot fully test the stored procedure in DB2.

Comment: First Cursors shouldn't be commonly used and only used when there is no other option because they are by design very slow and take way too many resources. A cursor is a loop in a sense. You use a select statement to load the cursor and after the select loads the cursor it will  iterate through it row by row. I am sure about the error it depends on how you handle errors.

Comment: IN AND OF ITSELF, a cursor is not a loop.  It's a pointer to a row/rowset (since RBAR is usually bad, most cursors are defined to return a block of records at a time).  Just opening the cursor doesn't give you any rows - you have to `FETCH` from it to get the data.  To make it a loop, you then have to `FETCH NEXT...` until the cursor reports "no more rows/rowsets, mate".  There's no difference to the SQL Server feature (other than SQL Server doesn't seem to allow blocks of rows).

Comment: @WesPalmer in DB2, a cursor is used to explicitly define the result set to return to the client.    MS SQL does this implicitly with just a `SELECT` in the body of the SP.

Answer (score 1):

To your first question: as mentioned in comments, opening a cursor does not produce a result set, but merely a (pointer to a) structure allowing you to access the result set using the `FETCH` statement or equivalent. Moreover, the result set may not even be fully materialized when you start fetching records -- this depends on the actual query and various cursor options.

To your second question: if your stored procedure returns, normally or otherwise, before opening the cursor, its caller will get an uninitialized cursor structure (which will cause an exception when you try to access it) and not an empty result set.