# Loading resultset using cursors - DB2 stored procedure

Tags: database, db2, cursor

I have created a stored procedure in Db2 which is something like

```
Declare c1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
              select * from table,...... -- joins and filters;
Declare c2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
              select * from table,...... -- joins and filters ;
Declare c3 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
              select * from table,...... -- joins and filters ;
```

In the end of the procedure, I open the cursor based on the condition. Something like this:

```
IF (input_value="employees") THEN
     OPEN c1;
ELSEIF (input_value="management") THEN
     OPEN c2;
ELSEIF (input_value="admin") THEN
     OPEN c3;
```

My concern is, when I execute this procedure, would it load all the three result sets in the memory and return the correct one based on condition, or would it just load one based on the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, results sets in general are not loaded into memory in their entirety. Db2 will materialize portions of a result set as you `FETCH` from its *open* cursor and send them to the client in blocks.

Secondly, until you `OPEN` a cursor no resources whatsoever are allocated, apart from those occupied by the cursor variable in your procedure code.

So, to answer your question, only one cursor will be opened in your code, and only rows from that result set will ever occupy any memory.

See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893607/is-this-db2-cursor-a-loop?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks! just wanted to confirm it